# Admob prevents TextView UI updates with a CountDownTimer in Android?

Tags: android, admob

I'm adding admob ads to my app that has a CountDownTimer that changes a time countdown display in its onTick() callback function. The time display uses a TextView and is changed via .setText().
Everything works fine until I add the admob code. Seems that the ads break the TextView redraws when running. When I stop the CountDownTimer and update the TextView, the redraw happens.
I'm not certain why this is happening, and since CountDownTimer is implemented using os.Handler, I can't think of a better way to do this. Calling TextView.invalidate doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually I've figured this out. It's because my time interval is too small. I changed the interval from 10 to 100 miliseconds, and the UI updates fine. Probably because of the extra overhead of the ad that the display got frozen.

Answer (score 0):

The AdMob ad SDK uses a few Timer constructions of its own. Those might be interfering with yours or making yours slower at the least. As you already said, raising your interval then helps.